# How to add PDF files in a database and be able to search for them through a website using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am working on a website and the owner wants to use PDF files to show the contents of a bill for users to see what they owe. He wants to be able to search through the website using specific search criteria. For example, the PDF number, a certain town, a certain year etc... I have a form already made to use to search for these PDF files, I just don't know how to store the PDF files in the database using phpMyAdmin. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't really need to store the PDF files, do you? You can just store the data used to construct their contents, and then recreate them on-the-fly?

Comment: This is a very broad question but I agree with Strawberry on this, the easiest and best way to handle this is to programmatically recreate the bill on demand. Make sure a random user can't just guess a URL to view the bill belonging to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep all the metadata and filename in the database and store the actual files in `uploads/` directory. When you search for a file by its ID, city or whatever, you'll retrieve the filename and you'll be able to redirect to a particular file.

Personally I'd change all filenames to `uniqid().'.pdf'` so that they don't repeat and have constant length.